# How can I upload HD video from iPhone 4 directly to web?

Tags: iphone, video, data-transfer

How can I upload HD video from iPhone 4 directly to web?

Comment: I see you had ask it on webapps, but it is probably more appropriate on this site. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/is-there-a-way-to-upload-higher-resolution-videos-to-youtube-or-any-video-sharin

Answer (score 3):

## Pixelpipe

From https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/is-there-a-way-to-upload-higher-resolution-videos-to-youtube-or-any-video-sharin

> This **free app allows iPhone 4 users to
> directly upload their 720P videos to
> YouTube**, as well as Flickr, Facebook,
> MobileMe, Viddler, Posterous and a
> whole slew of other video sharing
> sites. The app evens works via email
> and FTP. The only caveat is that the
> videos cannot be over 200 MB in size.

**Regarding with how to use it, check out this post:
http://islandinthenet.com/2010/07/06/pixelpipe-upload-720p-hd-video-from-iphone-4-to-youtube/
I recommend that post, it gives some great information on the app and how it is used.**

For example:

> A “pipe” is the
> connector between the PixelPipe app
> and one or more destination sites
> where you want your content to be
> uploaded. For example, I set up pipes
> for flickr, picasa, and Dropbox and
> many others.
>
> I setup some of my pipes as default
> routes. This means that any media I
> select to upload will automatically go
> to these default pipes.
>
> For each pipe
> I created, PixelPipe created a routing
> tag. The routing tag explicitly tells
> PixelPipe where to upload the content
> overriding any default routes. If you
> want your content routed to different
> photo sets you can create a routing
> pipe and tag for each one.

Also, given this:

> since other developers are sure to create a similar product now that they know it is possible to upload 720p videos.

**If you don't like the PixelPipe app, it shouldn't be too long before another solution pops up :)**

According to this page, an app called **SmugMug is also 720p uploading enabled**, however I couldn't find much in reference to that on their site.
http://www.tuaw.com/2010/07/01/want-to-upload-720p-from-iphone-4-try-pixelpipe/

Answer (score 0):

The [Flickr](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flickr/id328407587?mt=8) app will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps that do this. I like the following for ease of use and design. I'll rank them in the order of the quality of the final video (and coincidentally overall usability)

- [iMovie](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id377298193?mt=8) - very slick, great editing, many upload options like YouTube, Vimeo and others
- [Posterous](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/posterous/id394252521?mt=8) - very powerful blogging tool for free.
- [Vimeo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vimeo/id425194759?mt=8) - free but not [yet] as slick as iMovie

One last mention is a live streaming app called [Ustream Live Broadcaster](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ustream-live-broadcaster/id319362690?mt=8) - I don't really use it but it's unlike the rest in that it's more of a broadcast tool than for pushing something you captured to the web once the video is complete.